# ES Module Version of React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

I haven't had any luck finding any info about how or where to download a native, ES module version of react. I know they mention that they write most of their React-internal code in ES6+, so curious if there is an alternative to the current "react" package on NPM.

I was hoping Pika would find one, but no dice: https://www.pika.dev/search?q=react

Any help or insight would be wonderful. I've searched around quite a bit for a solution to this with no luck so far.

Comment: Questions searching for a tool or library are considered off-topic for stackoverflow. Also the search term "es module react" on google instantly gave me [this](https://github.com/lukejacksonn/es-react). There doesn't seem to be anything really better atm.

Comment: Hmm I missed that when I searched for some reason. Thank you!